# How to provide free tagging ability when saving nodes using services

Tags: taxonomy-terms, services

A content type is going to be saved , this type contains a taxonomy term reference field named field_ucectgry . I'm developing an app so the user can create new node types remotely. Services module is used to provide a REST service for that.

Now for filling field_ucectgry during node creation I must pass the term ID , but the problem is that this field must has free tagging ability which means new tokens for this field is accepted.

So , how can I provide the ability of free tagging for my program?

PS: this is the structure of the field in node :

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In D7, a taxonomy term reference field with the autocomplete widget uses **JSON** like this: 
`"field_tags":{"und":"Foo,Bar"}"` 
When it is an autocomplete, the term name needs to be used instead of the term id for free tagging it will simply create the term.

Comment: This error show up:
<result>
<form_errors>
<field_ucemake__und>An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator.</field_ucemake__und>
</form_errors>
</result>

Comment: this is my implementation : 
"field_ucemake":{"und":"AGCO"}